# What does gdata-java-api's CalendarEventEntry.getTimes() return?

Tags: google-calendar-api, gdata-api

I've been looking up and down the api-docs and couldn't find out if and when the method returns more than one `When` instance. The [code](http://google.com/codesearch#eNzMn1Vc2NE/trunk/sinads-paa-metquant/src/com/google/gdata/data/extensions/BaseEventEntry.java&q=BaseEventEntry&type=cs&l=74) seems to parse repeating occurrences of `<gd:when>` elements, the [common elements](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/elements.html#gdEventKind) section of the protocol description has a `*` after the `gd:when` property, indicating that there can be multiple elements of this type. But the description implies that there is only one event element.

So in which case does `CalendarEventEntry.getTimes()` return more than one `When` instance? It seems to be possible to add multiple instances via `addTime()`, but can you do it via the default web interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found in [Data API Developer's Guide: The Protocol: Section "Creating Recurring Events"](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingRecurring):

---

- No query parameters: a recurring event is returned as a single element or object, with a recurrence child element or property. No when elements or properties are included in the recurring event.
- start-min and/or start-max specified: a recurring event is represented as a single element or object, **with multiple when elements or objects for each occurrence in the range specified**. A recurrence is also included.
- singleevents=true: recurring events are represented in the same format as single events, with a single element or object per occurrence of the event. **Each event includes a single when element or object, but does not include the recurrence syntax.** It does, however, include an originalEvent element or property.